# ASP.NET 5 vNext, missing a using directive or an assembly reference CS0246

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, asp.net-core

I have problems with the packaging concept, building a new ASP.NET 5 application with e.g. Telerik parts.
DNX Core 5.0 doesn't want to accept the reference.
Does not works with another Class Library in the same solution either.
[image]

But declared everything correct (in my opinion) in **project.json:**

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Telerik.DataAccess.Fluent": "2015.2.624.2",
      "Telerik.DataAccess.Core": "2015.2.624.2",
      "Telerik.DataAccess.Web": "2015.2.624.2",
      "Telerik.DataAccess.Fluent.Sample": "2015.2.624.1"
    }
  },
  "dnxcore50": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Telerik.DataAccess.Fluent": "2015.2.624.2",
      "Telerik.DataAccess.Core": "2015.2.624.2",
      "Telerik.DataAccess.Web": "2015.2.624.2",
      "Telerik.DataAccess.Fluent.Sample": "2015.2.624.1"
    }
  }
},
```

It seems also fine in the project *References* tree:

[image]

Is there someone who got it or something similar working?

for google crawler:
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Telerik' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Andritz.Quots.DNX Core 5.0

Comment: Just remove dnxcore50 from project.json

Comment: Why are dnx451 and dnxcore50 in project.json per default?

Comment: It's still beta. I guess they will add a checkbox in the future when selecting a project template to select if the project should run on core framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Vitaly's hint,
just remove **dnxcore50** target. It's now compiling..

The extended answer is, that in this case, the Telerik components are most likely not prepared for targeting Core 5.0 .

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Telerik.DataAccess.Fluent": "2015.2.624.2",
      "Telerik.DataAccess.Core": "2015.2.624.2",
      "Telerik.DataAccess.Web": "2015.2.624.2",
      "Telerik.DataAccess.Fluent.Sample": "2015.2.624.1"
    }
  }
},
```

additional information thread, treating this:
https://forums.couchbase.com/t/using-couchbase-net-sdk-client-with-asp-net-5-mvc6-in-vs-2015-rtm/4568

ASP.NET 5 Documentation
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/aspnet/latest/aspnet.pdf